# Rank Calculation in PHP

Tags: php

I want to calculate the rank of the students. Condition for rank calculation is, If two or more students have same total marks they all will get same rank. Then the next rank will start from Previous_rank + Number of Duplicate records.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$numbers = array( 101, 201, 301, 301, 401, 501, 501);
rsort($numbers);

$arrlength = count($numbers);
$rank = 1;
   $rt=0;
for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {
    if ($x==0) {
         echo $numbers[$x]."- Rank".($rank);
    }

   elseif ($numbers[$x] != $numbers[($x-1)]) {

            echo $numbers[$x]."- Rank".($rank);
            $rt=$rank;
           }
   else{
        echo $numbers[$x]."- Rank".($rt);
            }
      $rank++;
   echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

My Expected output is like

```
501- Rank1
501- Rank1
401- Rank3
301- Rank4
301- Rank4
201- Rank6
101- Rank7
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code does what you want

```
        <?php
$numbers = array( 101, 201, 301, 301, 401, 401, 401, 501, 501, 501, 501);
rsort($numbers);

$arrlength = count($numbers);
$rank = 1;
$prev_rank = $rank;

for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {

    if ($x==0) {
         echo $numbers[$x]."- Rank".($rank);
    }

   elseif ($numbers[$x] != $numbers[$x-1]) {
        $rank++;
        $prev_rank = $rank;
        echo $numbers[$x]."- Rank".($rank);
   }

   else{
        $rank++;
        echo $numbers[$x]."- Rank".($prev_rank);
    }

   echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

The problem was with the $rt variable, which you set to 0 but instead should have tracked the previous rank.

Comment: `$numbers = array( 101, 201, 301, 301, 401, 501, 501, 501, 501);` Its not working for this marks

Comment: Use the below code @VadivelMuruganM https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38369597/rank-calculation-in-php/60948279#60948279

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

    $numbers = array( 101, 201, 301, 301, 401, 501, 501,601,701,701,701,801,901);

    rsort($numbers);

    $arr = $arr1 = array();

    foreach ($numbers as $key => $value) {
        $arr[$value][] = $value;
    }

    $i = $j = 1;

    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {

        foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1) {
            echo $key."- Rank".$i;
            echo "<br>";
            $j++;
        }
    $i = $j;

    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Still we can reduce loops

```
 <?php

$numbers = array( 101, 201, 301, 301, 401, 501, 501,601,701,701,701,801,901);
rsort($numbers);
$rank=1;
$prev=$numbers[0];
foreach($numbers as $number){
  if($prev!=$number){
    $prev=$number;
    $rank++;
  }
  echo $number."=>Rank -".$rank."\n";
}
?>
```

Same output but removed unnecessary loops.

Answer (score 0):

PHP code with single loop that works for all cases

```
rsort($numbers);

$arrlength = count($numbers);
$rank = 1;
$prev_rank = $rank;
for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {
    if ($x==0) {
         echo $numbers[$x]."- Rank".($rank);
    }elseif ($numbers[$x] != $numbers[$x-1]) {
        $rank++;
        $prev_rank = $rank;
        echo $numbers[$x]."- Rank".($rank);
   }else{
        $rank;
        echo $numbers[$x]."- Rank".($prev_rank);
    }
   echo "<br>";
}
?>
```